# Changing a TextField text for items in a foreach NavigationLink SwiftUI and saving it

Tags: swiftui, foreach, textfield, swiftui-navigationlink

There is a list in on the Main View that has navigation links that bring you to a an Edit Birthday View where the textFieldName is saved with the onAppear method. I need help in allowing the user to change the text in the text field on the Edit Birthday View and having it save when the user dismisses and returns to that particular item in the foreach list. I have tried onEditingChanged and on change method but they don't seem to work. (Also, in my view model i append birthday items when they are created in the Add Birthday View). If you would like to see more code i will make updates. Thank you.

/// MAIN VIEW

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: BirthdayViewModel
    @State var nameTextField: String = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.searchableUsers, id: \.self) { birthday in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditBirthdayView(birthday: birthday))  {
                        BirthdayRowView(birthday: birthday)
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: vm.deleteBirthday)
            }
        }

        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                NavigationLink(destination: AddBirthdayView(textfieldName: $nameTextField)) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// EDIT BIRTHDAY VIEW

import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct EditBirthdayView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: BirthdayViewModel
    
    @State var textfieldName: String = ""
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var birthday: BirthdayModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
 
                TextField("Name...", text: $textfieldName)
                }
         
                Button {
                    saveButtonPressed()
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }                
            }            
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                    textfieldName = birthday.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveButtonPressed() {
        vm.updateItem(birthday: birthday)
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
    func updateTextField() {
        textfieldName = birthday.name
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere a function that updates the model based on the value of the text field, `textfieldName`. Shouldn't `saveButtonPressed` be passing that value to the view model somehow? On a side note, I don't understand the need for the `DispatchQueue` inside the `.onAppear` modifier.

Comment: @HunterLion Thanks for the response. I have been having trouble with the update function. I believe I should pass in a BirthdayModel but within the function I am hitting a road block.

Comment: Try adding `birthday.name = textFieldName` before the line `vm.updateItem(birthday: birthday)`. Your code is changing the view variable, but then you need to change the value in the model somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: BirthdayStore
        
    var body: some View {
        List {
                ForEach($store.birthdays) { $birthday in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditBirthdayView(birthday: $birthday))  {
                        BirthdayRowView(birthday: birthday)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteBirthday)
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                NavigationLink(destination: AddBirthdayView() {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct EditBirthdayView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: BirthdayStore
    
    @Binding var birthday: Birthday

...

    TextField("Name", text: $birthday.name)
```